# jqGrid drag and drop to subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

Has anyone been implemented Drag and Drop from one jqGrid to a subgrid of another JqGrid. so basically i have a look grid where i can search and filter for what i want and drag a row to another grid with subgrids.

lookup grid (food)
recording grid (main grid (week) -> childgrid(day) -> childgrid(foodlist)

so my drag and drop would go from the lookupgrid to the foodlist subgrid for that day.

i have implemented the lookup grid and the recording grid but cannot do the drag and drop functionality.

the issue is that jqGrid is using static grid ID as per the documentation, however the subgrid ID are dynanmic and cannot be linked using the documentation recommendation

```
        jQuery("#jqGrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqGrid2'}); 
        jQuery("#jqGrid2").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqGrid1'});
```

any wizard out there that can make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) approach, then the subgrid is just one more grid which you create inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. Thus I see no problem to call `gridDnD` inside of `subGridRowExpanded` directly after creating the subgrid.

Comment: the way i see it i have to predefine the connected grid like jQuery("#jqGrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqGrid2'}); however subGridRowExpanded a new childgridID is created depending on which row is selected. so basically inside the

Comment: That is true, just needed that step back and a new fresh set of eyes to point me to the right direction. For those interested here is how it worked for me. 

inside the  function 
showChildGrid(parentRowID, parentRowKey) { ....
................
.......................
  $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({ ....
  ......................
  }
// added the connection here to the dynamic grid
jQuery("#jlookupGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#'+ childGridID});
} 

Thanks Oleg

Comment: @boulepick: You are welcome! The syntax `{connectWith:'#jqGrid2'}` menas just anonymous object with `connectWith` property. You can use any variable as the value of `connectWith`. For example you can use something like `{connectWith:'#' + subgrid_table_id}` as the parameter of `gridDnD`. From the point of view of JavaScript the parameter `{connectWith:'#jqGrid2'}` is in the same way dynamic like `{connectWith:'#' + subgrid_table_id}`. Both creates *dynamically* object with one `connectWith` property and assign the value to the property. In any way, I'm glad that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use draggable and droppable methods provided bu jQuery UI. Specify the ID of the target subgrid as the *droppable* area. While performing the drop, update the underlying data as well.

```
$("#gbox_destinationTable tr td").droppable({
    drop : function(event, ui) {
        var draggedHtml = ui.draggable.html();
        $(this).append(draggedHtml);
        deleteFromSource(ui.draggable.parent());
    } 
 });

function deleteFromSource(draggedObj) {
    $('#sourceTable').jqGrid('delRowData', draggedObj.attr('id'));
}
```

You may see a sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/pragya91/fzkqxdxm/